Map key to its child value attribute
I have a simple YAML:
host1:
  type: A
  value: 10.0.0.1
host2:
  type: A
  value: 10.0.0.2

which I want to map key-value pairs, like this:
host1: 10.0.0.1
host2: 10.0.0.2

How can I do this using yq?

Apply .value to all items of the root:
.[] |= .value
# or
map_values(.value)

Works with both kislyuk/yq and mikefarah/yq.
